# Do any ORM frameworks allow choreography of multiple database inserts

Tags: orm, db2, zos

I have a requirement to perform the following steps (stages/phases) when updating my database.

1. Validate business request to ensure it is valid.
2. Identify what database records need creating.
3. Create these records as Java Objects, populated with the necessary instance variable values.
4. Persist multiple records in the required sequence (e.g. Parent(s) then Child(ren)) within one transaction.
5. Repeat process for next Business request.

My entire database consists of over 600 tables.
Some business requests result in 30 to 40 tables requiring new data to be inserted.
I am looking for a process where i can instantiate all my Java entity objects, populate them with the required data. Then

- Begin Transaction,
- choreograph inserts,
- commit.

am i going to have to be the choreographer?
My database is IBM db2 v10 for z/os.
My development environment is Java 7, IBM Websphere Application Server v8.5.5

Comment: When copying the question from somewhere else, please format the text. Otherwise is impossible to understand.

Comment: I tried formatting, and failed. Why doesn't be work anymore?

Comment: Formatting is not addinde html tags

Comment: why doesnt stackoverflow have a simple accessible rich text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z/OS has a built in transaction manager, RRS.  You can use it as your transaction manager.  I think you do automatically if you connect via WAS, but I'm not that familiar with it, so I can't say for sure.  I'd suggest looking at the "DB2 for z/OS and WebSphere Integration for Enterprise Java Applications" redbook, here:  http://books.google.com/books?id=UfjHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA589&dq=DB2+for+z/OS+and+WebSphere+Integration+for+Enterprise+Java+Applications+redbook&hl=en&sa=X&ei=luypU82THI6uyAT7pIGgDQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=DB2%20for%20z%2FOS%20and%20WebSphere%20Integration%20for%20Enterprise%20Java%20Applications%20redbook&f=false

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at my (badly formatted) question. Sadly RSS is not the solution to my particular issue. What i am looking for is an "off the shelf" choreographer that will ensure multiple database tables are updated "In the correct sequence" within a unit of work. i would like to be able to instantiate java objects In no particular order) that represent my underlying db2 tables (with parent and child relationships). Once all my java objects exist (and are populated with the correct data) i perform a single method which persists all these objects into my underlying database.